# How can I convert this Json array in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-json

I have an array like this and I want to extract its count into a single array. Can I do this in SQL Server?

```
[
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM1",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "Count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 20
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM2",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 25
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I want to convert this as following. How can I achieve this using SQL Server?

```
[
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM1",
    "Details": [10, 20, 30]
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM2",
    "Details": [10, 25, 2]
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

It ain't pretty but:

```sql
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
[
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM1",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 20
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM2",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 25
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]'

SELECT  JSON_MODIFY(    -- We want to modify Details part inside the Item array
        x.value -- Contains whole json
    ,   '$.Details'  -- Path to the field we wanna replace
    ,   JSON_QUERY(  -- Value we replace with. It's important to use JSON_QUERY, otherwise SQL Server will create a string
            '['  -- Array start
            + STUFF( -- STUFF part is is to remove to first "," from the ,10,20,30 string
                (   -- This monstrosity builds a comma separated list of count strings
                    SELECT  ',' + cast(JSON_VALUE(value, '$.count') AS NVARCHAR(MAX))
                    FROM    OPENJSON(x.value, '$.Details') -- This iterates the elements under details
                    ORDER BY CAST([key] AS INT) -- We want to preserve sorting of the counts
                    FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') -- This sucker gets a "text" from XML as a string
                , 1, 1, '') 
            + ']' -- Finally end array
        )
    )
FROM    OPENJSON(@json) x -- This iterates the array and creates one row per "ItemName"
```

I think in newer versions (like SQL Server 2022), you can create arrays in simpler ways (https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/azure-sql-blog/announcing-json-enhancements-in-azure-sql-database-azure-sql/ba-p/3417071)

Comment: I'm a SQL 2016 guy, but if you are on 2017 etc you can also use:
'['  +(
SELECT STRING_AGG(cast(JSON_VALUE(value, '$.count') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ',') within group (ORDER BY CAST([key] AS INT)) 
FROM OPENJSON(x.value, '$.Details')
)
+ ']'

to simplify the array building a bit

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'
[
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM1",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 20
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 30
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "ItemName": "ITEM2",
    "Details": [
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Apr",
        "count": 10
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/May",
        "count": 25
      },
      {
        "column1": "2021\/Jun",
        "count": 2
      }
    ]
  }
]'

SELECT      x.ItemName
            , JSON_QUERY('[' + STRING_AGG(s.count, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY s.Column1) + ']') AS Details
FROM        OPENJSON(@json)
WITH        (
            ItemName    NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.ItemName'
            , Details   NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.Details' AS JSON
            ) x
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(x.Details)
WITH        (
            Column1     NVARCHAR(MAX)   '$.column1'
            , Count     INT             '$.count'
            ) s
GROUP BY    x.ItemName
FOR JSON PATH
```

The idea is that you can `CROSS APPLY` more `OPENJSON` on columns parsed with `AS JSON`

To produce an array of scalars just concatenate `count`s with comma delimiter ordered by `column1`, wrap in square brackets and mark with `JSON_QUERY` not to be treated as a string but as a full-bloodied JSON array by final `FOR JSON PATH`.